# AWS ECS Service never deploys on second capacity provider, "unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Scenario:

- two identically configured autoscaling groups, one using on-demand and one using spot instances
- two capacity providers registered with the ECS cluster as "EC2" and "EC2_SPOT", pointing to the autoscaling groups
- both ASGs / capacity providers have one instance in them
- both instances correctly show up in the ECS Cluster
- one service that is configured to start 2 tasks, with the following capacity provider strategy:

```
capacity_provider_strategy {
    base              = 1
    capacity_provider = "EC2"
    weight            = 1
}

"capacity_provider_strategy" {
    capacity_provider = "EC2_SPOT"
    weight            = 1
}
```

Expected behavior: the service starts one task on the EC2 capacity provider, satisfying the "base = 1" constraint. It then starts the next task on EC2_SPOT, satisfying the "weight = 1" constraint. Further tasks should be placed 50% each on EC2 and EC2_SPOT.

Actual behavior: one task starts on the EC2 provider successfully. Then the Service throws the following error "service test was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements."

Removing the "base = 1" constraint solves this issue.

Question: Am I misunderstanding how the capacity provider strategy is supposed to work?